# Where did this site come from?

Tags: discussion

I contributed many example questions and discussions to the previous (failed) Area51 proposal for a Coffee site a few years ago. And I didn't even know about this one until seeing it on the SE dropdown menu *yesterday*!

So, bluntly, what did you guys do *right* the we did *wrong*? And how come you didn't (or, why don't we go and ...) invite old committers from previous proposals?

The last proposal seemed to die when it was discovered that Coffee issues are all on-topic at Seasoned Advice. How did you guys jump that hurdle??

Comment: I believe this question was mostly covered in our commitment stage: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/19292/wouldnt-almost-every-question-here-be-on-topic-for-seasoned-advice

Comment: I believe there was a shift in policy on Area51 proposals.  Some larger sites have such a broad range of on-topic material that most of us (I think) began to articulate the conditions in which having a "splinter" group (narrower focus with potentially deeper specialization) is desirable.

Comment: See also http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/a/1157/230, notably "A weighty argument that a new community exists that does not identify themselves as part of the larger subject" -- as far as I could tell, roughly what happened is that the coffee aficionados were stubborn enough about wanting a separate site (i.e. they weren't willing to participate on Seasoned Advice) that they convinced people that this point applied.

Comment: @Jefromi I completely understand that. [I tried too](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37400/how-do-you-use-the-gizmo-for-caf%c3%a9-sua-da) but it just wasn't what I was looking for.